# How to return total value for each company using eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, return-value

so i have this table on database

```
+---------+------------+-------+
| Company |  periods   | value |
+---------+------------+-------+
| a1      | 01-01-2018 |  1000 |
| a1      | 01-02-2018 |   600 |
| a2      | 01-01-2018 |   500 |
| a2      | 01-03-2018 |   500 |
| a3      | 01-01-2018 |   500 |
| a3      | 01-02-2018 |   500 |
| a3      | 01-03-2018 |   500 |
+---------+------------+-------+
```

and what i expect to get on query is to be like if i want to get all company total value for 01-02-2018 then it will be summarize the value for each company until 01-02-2018

```
+---------+------------+-------+
| Company |  periods   | value |
+---------+------------+-------+
| a1      | 01-02-2018 |  1600 |
| a2      | 01-02-2018 |   500 |
| a3      | 01-02-2018 |  1000 |
+---------+------------+-------+
```

and if i want to get total value form 01-03-2018 then it also will summarize the value for each company until 01-03-2018

```
+---------+------------+-------+
| Company |  periods   | value |
+---------+------------+-------+
| a1      | 01-03-2018 |  1600 |
| a2      | 01-03-2018 |  1000 |
| a3      | 01-03-2018 |  1500 |
+---------+------------+-------+
```

how to do that on eloquent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is like this,

when you group rows by 'value' column, in the result row what is gonna be the 'periods' value? you know there were several distinct 'period' values before you group. now among them, which 'period' value should MySQL put into your result row...?

so its not allowed by '**sql_mode=only_full_group_by**'

either you need to remove 'periods' column from select query or you can aggregate the 'periods' column.

Possible solutions.

```
$maxDate = // whatever date you wanna compare with.

$summery = Model::select(DB::row('Company, max(periods) AS periods, sum(value) AS value'))
    ->groupBy('Company')
    ->where('periods', '<=', $maxDate)
    ->get();
```

Comment: okay i think this code will works, but just wondering when i add for example: the created_at column on select query inside DB::row then i will get 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column error... so do i need to aggregate all other column beside company column?

Comment: this is the error i pointed out about 'periods' column. either remove 'periods' column from select query or use max(period).

Comment: ohh.... then how about if this table have a relationship? like say it is belongsTo relation with company table that i want to show the company name on this query?

Comment: its ok, because you grouped by company. so you can have company name column for the select query. because there are 'EXACT', 'UNAMBIGUOUS' company name for each row of the select.

Comment: oh okay then i think this is good enough... so i just need to add max(column_name) as column_name to all other column....

Comment: exactly. max or any other reasonable aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Use groupBy:

```
$point_history = Model::select(['Company', 'periods',DB::raw('sum(value) as value')])
                ->groupBy('Company')
                ->having('periods','01-02-2018')
                ->get();
```

write periods condition in having as your requirement

Comment: i get this error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'laravelvue.report.periods' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: edit question and post your code so everyone can check.

Answer (score 0):

```
$from = date('2018-01-01');
$to = date('2018-02-01');

$data = Model::select(DB::raw('Company', 'periods', 'sum(value) as total_value'))
                ->groupBy('Company')
                ->whereBetween('periods', [$from, $to])
                ->get();
```

Can you try the above code? `$form` date should be the very first date from where you started recording. You should change the `$to` date to get the total summery time to time.