# How to only return summarize value from belongsTo table with specific condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, return-value

so i have this kind of report table on my database

```
+---------+------------+-------+
| Company |  periods   | value |
+---------+------------+-------+
| a1      | 01-01-2018 |  1000 |
| a1      | 01-02-2018 |   600 |
| a2      | 01-01-2018 |   500 |
| a2      | 01-03-2018 |   500 |
| a3      | 01-01-2018 |   500 |
| a3      | 01-02-2018 |   500 |
| a3      | 01-03-2018 |   500 |
+---------+------------+-------+
```

and this table have `belongsTo` relationship with company table that also have soft delete feature

```
+----+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name |     created_at      |     deleted_at      |
+----+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| a1 | zzzz | 2018-09-30 08:45:27 | null                |
| a2 | xxxx | 2018-03-02 15:35:01 | 2018-02-26 15:35:01 |
| a3 | yyyy | 2018-12-15 14:20:33 | null                |
+----+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

now continuing from [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52529085/how-to-return-total-value-for-each-company-using-eloquent/52531294?noredirect=1#comment92003280_52531294) which already have answer. On that question i want to show sum of the value from specific periods for each company and this is working fine.

now i find another requirement that i needed, well it is kinda complicated, so continuing from the first question, i also like for example when i want sum from period 01-02-2018 then it will show like this (which again already have the answer on the question above)

```
+---------+------------+-------+
| Company |  periods   | value |
+---------+------------+-------+
| a1      | 01-02-2018 |  1600 |
| a2      | 01-02-2018 |   500 |
| a3      | 01-02-2018 |  1000 |
+---------+------------+-------+
```

the question in here is if i want to sum from period 01-03-2018 then it will only show only company a1 and a3 since a2 is closed/deleted at 26-02-2018 so it will be out of the sum

```
+---------+------------+-------+
| Company |  periods   | value |
+---------+------------+-------+
| a1      | 01-03-2018 |  1600 |
| a3      | 01-03-2018 |  1500 |
+---------+------------+-------+
```

how to do that? i tried to add on report model

```
public function Company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company','company','id')->where('deleted_at',null);
}
```

and then just

```
$sum = Report::with('Company')->addSelect(DB::row('Company, max(periods) AS periods, sum(value) AS value'))
    ->groupBy('Company')
    ->where('periods', '<=', $maxDate)
    ->get();
```

but its not working....

Comment: `Report::with('company')`, try `Report::with('Company')`. "C" is capital same as your function name.

Comment: hmm that is only some typos i do when rewritting the code to here in stackoverflow hahaha... but that is not the main question